# Android SharedPreferences not preserved after app exits

Tags: android

I have a app that makes use of SharedPreferences. After I close the application by pressing the back button (app still in background) and reenter the app, the values stored in the preferences are still there.

However, after I stop the app (stop completely) and re-open it, the preference is gone.

I've checked different possibilities including missing calling `commit()` in `Editor`, but with no success.

This is my code in the `onCreate` method:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
cookie = prefs.getString("cookie", "");
```

After the app exits completely `cookie` is set to ""

And my code for storing preference:

```
prefs.edit().putString("cookie", cookie).commit();
```

Comment: with stop you mean uninstall or clear data from app settings?

Comment: Agreed -- please explain what "stop the app" means. Also, please explain what "app exits completely" means.

Comment: Here I mean going to settings and force stop the app, not reinstalling nor clearing data.

Comment: What does the variable cookie contain#

Answer (score 0):

This question of mine is now meaningless.

The thing is, I'm working on someone else's code, in the `onDestroy()` method all the prefs, files, and cache are deleted manually.

Uhh..